# What is the minimum about the function $u$ we must have to use Green's formula?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

In Evans' book Partial Differential Equations, appendix C.2 Theorem 3, Green's formulas are established: Let $u, v \in C^{2}( \overline{U})$. Then
$$ \int_U Du \cdot Dv dx = - \int_U u \Delta v dx + \int_{\partial U } \dfrac{\partial v }{\partial \nu } u dS .$$

My question is, is this formula valid requiring less about the $u$ function? For example, if $u \in H^1(U)$ or in some other sobolev space? or some other space? I'm interested in the case $U = \mathbb{R}^N$, if something is only valid in $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Comment: What do you want to assume of $v$? For the case $U=\mathbb R^n$, the above formula is valid without the boundary integral term if $u\in H^1(\mathbb R^n)$ and you still assume $v\in C^2(\mathbb R)$ for example.

Comment: I think you need some decay conditions on $v$ and its derivatives as well

Comment: Yes, I agree. You need $\nabla v, \Delta v\in L^2(\mathbb R^n)$